# Conflict issue while updating list item with attachments

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013

I created a custom form which has dynamic subform as well. **for eg:** the custom form consist of 3 sections:

1. Parent form.
2. Attachment control
3. Sub form with add/remove button for creating multiple subforms.

Here how my script works for adding the data: Parent form gets submitted and it returns item ID using jsom. And based on that item ID, Attachments are added to parent form and sub-form data gets added in another list. But sometimes, i am facing conflict issue while adding attachments and here is the code:

```js
if (flag == true) {
        oLoader = SP.UI.ModalDialog.showWaitScreenWithNoClose("Working on it", "Creating a new Request...");
        var data = [];
        var fileArray = [];
        $("#attachFilesContainer input:file").each(function () {
            if ($(this)[0].files[0]) {
                fileArray.push({ "Attachment": $(this)[0].files[0] });
            }
        });
        arraycount += fileArray.length;

        data.push({
            "Column_x0020_Name": $("#txtAccountNumber").val(),
            "Warehouse_x0020_Code": $("#wareHousedrpdown option:selected").text(),
            "Facility": $("#Facilitydrpdown option:selected").text(),
            "Internal_x002f_External": $("#InternalExteralDrpdown :selected").text(),
            "Requested_x0020_Completion_x0020": newReqDate,//$("#txtRequestedCompletionDate").datepicker('getDate').format('MM/dd/yyyy'),  //$("#txtRequestedCompletionDate").val(),
            "Account_x0020_Management_x0020_A": AccountName,
            "Quote_x0020_Required_x003f_": $("#drpQuoteRequired :selected").text(),
            "Files": fileArray
        });

        createItemWithAttachments("Parent", data).then(
           function () {
           
              oLoader.close(); 
              window.location.replace(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/Lists/Parent/AllItems.aspx");

   
                //if (oLoader.close) setTimeout(function () { oLoader.close(); window.location.replace(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/Lists/Test/AllItems.aspx"); }, 3000);
               //alert('Item created with Multiple attachments');
           },
           
                 
           function (sender, args) {
               console.log('Error occured' + args.get_message());
           }
           
       )
         //oLoader.close(); 
           //window.location.replace(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/Lists/Parent/AllItems.aspx");




    }
    
    function createSubformItem(listName,i) {
    var listItem = {
          __metadata: { "type": "SP.Data.SubFormListItem" },
             "ParentID": id,
     "Start_x0020_SKU":$("input[id='txtStartSKU" + i + "']").val(),
     "Qty_x0020_Requested":$("input[id='txtQtyRequested" + i + "']").val(),
     "UOM":$("#UOMdrpdown" + i + " option:selected").val(),
     "SSRType":$("#SSRTypedrpdown" + i + " option:selected").val()!="null" ? { "__metadata": { "type": "Collection(Edm.String)" }, "results": $("#SSRTypedrpdown"+i+"").val() } : { "__metadata": { "type": "Collection(Edm.String)" }, "results": [""] },
     "Hold_x0020_Type":$("#SSRHoldTypedrpdown" + i + " option:selected").val(),
     "End_x0020_SKU":$("input[id='txtEndSKU" + i + "']").val(),
     "Billing_x0020_UOM":$("#BillingUOMdrpdown" + i + " option:selected").val(),
     "Price_x0020_per_x0020_UOM":$("input[id='txtPricePerUOM" + i + "']").val(),
     "Instructions":$("textarea[title='Instructions" + i + "']").val(),
                                       
    };
    return $.ajax({
        url:"http://devapp/app/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('SubForm')/items",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        data: JSON.stringify(listItem),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        }
    });
}

var createItemWithAttachments = function (listName, listValues) {
    var fileCountCheck = 0;
    var fileNames;
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    var targetList = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listName);
    context.load(targetList);
    var singleUser = listValues[0].Account_x0020_Management_x0020_A != "" ? SP.FieldUserValue.fromUser(listValues[0].Account_x0020_Management_x0020_A) : null;
    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    var listItem = targetList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
    listItem.set_item("Account_x0020_Number", listValues[0].Account_x0020_Number);
    listItem.set_item("Warehouse_x0020_Code", listValues[0].Warehouse_x0020_Code);
    listItem.set_item("Facility", listValues[0].Facility);
    listItem.set_item("Internal_x002f_External", listValues[0].Internal_x002f_External);
    listItem.set_item("Requested_x0020_Completion_x0020", listValues[0].Requested_x0020_Completion_x0020);
    listItem.set_item("Account_x0020_Management_x0020_A", singleUser);
    listItem.set_item("Quote_x0020_Required_x003f_", listValues[0].Quote_x0020_Required_x003f_);

    listItem.update();
    for (i = 0; i <= count; i++) 
       {

              createSubformItem("SubForm",i);
             
             }

    context.executeQueryAsync(
        function () {
            id = listItem.get_id();
            if (listValues[0].Files.length != 0) {
                if (fileCountCheck <= listValues[0].Files.length - 1) {
                    loopFileUpload(listName, id, listValues, fileCountCheck).then(
                        function () {
                        },
                        function (sender, args) {
                            console.log("Error uploading");
                            dfd.reject(sender, args);
                        }
                    );
                }
            }
            else {
                dfd.resolve(fileCountCheck);
            }
        },
        function (sender, args) {
            console.log('Error occured' + args.get_message());
        }
    );
    return dfd.promise();
}

/*End of */


function loopFileUpload(listName, id, listValues, fileCountCheck) {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    uploadFile(listName, id, listValues[0].Files[fileCountCheck].Attachment).then(
        function (data) {
            var objcontext = new SP.ClientContext();
            var targetList = objcontext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listName);
            var listItem = targetList.getItemById(id);
            objcontext.load(listItem);
            objcontext.executeQueryAsync(function () {
                console.log("Reload List Item- Success");
                fileCountCheck++;
                if (fileCountCheck <= listValues[0].Files.length - 1) {
                    loopFileUpload(listName, id, listValues, fileCountCheck);
                } else {
                    console.log(fileCountCheck + ": Files uploaded");
                    attcount += fileCountCheck;
                    if (arraycount == attcount) {
                  for (i = 0; i <= count; i++) 
        {
               createSubformItem("SubForm",i);
              
              }
              oLoader.close(); 
              window.location.replace(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/Lists/ParentList/AllItems.aspx");
                        
                    }
                    
                }
            },
            function (sender, args) {
                console.log("Reload List Item- Fail" + args.get_message());
            });

        },
        function (sender, args) {
            console.log("Not uploaded");
            dfd.reject(sender, args);
        }
   );
    return dfd.promise();
}
function uploadFile(listName, id, file) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    var fileName = file.name;
    getFileBuffer(file).then(
        function (buffer) {
            var bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
            var binary = '';
            for (var b = 0; b < bytes.length; b++) {
                binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[b]);
            }
            var scriptbase = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_layouts/15/";
            console.log(' File size:' + bytes.length);
            $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.RequestExecutor.js", function () {
                var createitem = new SP.RequestExecutor(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl);
                createitem.executeAsync({
                    url: _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('" + listName + "')/items(" + id + ")/AttachmentFiles/add(FileName='" + file.name + "')",
                    method: "POST",
                    binaryStringRequestBody: true,
                    body: binary,
                    success: fsucc,
                    error: ferr,
                    state: "Update"
                });
                function fsucc(data) {
                    console.log(data + ' uploaded successfully');
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                }
                function ferr(data) {
                    console.log(fileName + "not uploaded error");
                    deferred.reject(data);
                }
            });

        },
        function (err) {
            deferred.reject(err);
        }
    );
    return deferred.promise();
}
function getFileBuffer(file) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        deferred.resolve(e.target.result);
    }
    reader.onerror = function (e) {
        deferred.reject(e.target.error);
    }
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that upload another attachment before SharePoint is done processing the item with larger files. So when you try to perform another operation on the item (adding another attachment, etc) a race condition is is reached and SharePoint throws the error. When the attachment files are smaller, the process has time to complete before you start the next upload.

You need to find a way to check if the item has completed it's processing. One way of doing this might be to do a get and check the item's etag and ensure that it has incremented the correct number of times before sending another POST.

Comment: Can you please help me out with this?